# How could I give KVM more hard disk space

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I want to use Kvm as hypervisor, but it is difficult. Is says that I don't have space on the node, that is not true.

How could I solve this big problem? http://prntscr.com/2rlcq1

Comment: Where do you wanna install Kvm ? Give us the specification of the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. First of all you can install `Kvm` only in a `bare-metal` physical machine. Though it comes with a `linux distribution` but it's a `hypervisor` so it runs directly on the hardware.

Next you have to enable the processor virtualization extension that is `Intel-VT/VT-x or AMD-v` from bios.

Then only you can install Kvm.

Comment: Kvm is already installed, i only ask a simple question. How could I add more space to the directory with image files?